# lseek issues

Tags: c

I'm having a hard time figuring out why `lseek` doesn't work properly. Basically all I need to do is take input from the standard input, store it into a file named "log.txt" and let the program stop as the "STOP" word is encountered.

My problem is as I try to run the program I get an lseek error: illegal seek and I don't know why. I thought the issue was the call to lseek but if I substitute `lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_END)` with `lseek(fd, atol(0), SEEK_END)` I get a segmentation fault.

I'm just so confused, I don't know how to proceed in order to fix this, I hope you could give your advice.

```
int fd;
char buffer[SIZE];
int n, cur;

if (fd = open("log.txt", O_RDWR, S_IRWXU|S_IRWXG|S_IRWXO) < 0)
{
    perror("Error: open");
    return 1;
}

if ((cur = lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_END)) < 0)
{
    printf("Offset corrente: %d\n", (int) lseek(fd, SIZE, SEEK_CUR));
    perror("Error: lseek");
    return 2;
}

while ((n = read(fd, buffer, SIZE)) > 0 && (strncmp(buffer, "STOP", 4) != 0))
{
    write(fd, buffer, SIZE);
}
```

Comment: The code `atol(0)` will always generate a segmentation fault.  This is because `atol` takes a string (like all of the "atoX" functions... "a" means string...), strings in C are pointers, and 0 is the NULL pointer.

Comment: Yeah `atol("0")` would work but why do the extra convert string to long, just pass in the long.

Comment: Well I'm open to any solution because I keep on getting the same mistake over and over again. Illegal seek.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (fd = open("log.txt", O_RDWR, S_IRWXU|S_IRWXG|S_IRWXO) < 0)
```

should be

```
if ((fd = open("log.txt", O_RDWR, S_IRWXU|S_IRWXG|S_IRWXO)) < 0)
```

otherwise it will be parsed as

```
if (fd = (open("log.txt", O_RDWR, S_IRWXU|S_IRWXG|S_IRWXO) < 0))
```

(because `<` has a higher operator precedence than `=`); if the `open()` succeeds, it will return a value that is >= 0, so the expression `open(...) < 0` will be false, so `fd` will be set to 0.

File descriptor 0 represents the standard input for your process.  Unless you've redirected it, this will be a terminal device, for which seeking is illegal.

Comment: Thank you very much!! I wasn't really thinking that the problem could be elsewhere, I was getting crazy! Thank you again! :)

Answer (score 3):

You are reading and writing to the same file

```
 read(fd, buffer, SIZE)
```

Is wrong.  You want to read from stdin.

Comment: I totally missed that!! Thank you, but I still get the error, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

```
if ((cur = lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_END)) < 0)
```

should be changed to:

```
if ((cur = lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_END)) == -1)
```

In certain situations it is possible for lseek to provide a negative offset. As a result when testing for an error, only x == -1 should be used, instead of x < 0.

Answer (score 1):

Not only are you reading the same file, read() reads SIZE bytes. 
Unless your input is fixed length records of SIZE bytes you will read multiple lines, completely missing the STOP which is now in the middle of the buffer.

while ( fgets( buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin) && (strncmp(buffer, "STOP", 4) != 0))

Reads a line at a time.